# SEM-Path analysis based on the binary outcome(independent variable) in R

Tags: r

I would like to conduct SEM-Path analysis in R.

As I know, the basic SEM analysis should be based on the continuous outcome (independent variable).

On the other hand, I want to do analysis based on the binary outcome.

Is there any method to solve this problem?

Thanks advanced.

Comment: There are SEM models for ordered categorical outcomes. They typically use an ordered logistic model to predict the outcome. The lavaan package fits these models in R. You'll need to read up on the modelling syntax, but if you make the binary outcome an ordered factor (e.g., `dat$binary_outcome <- ordered(dat$binary_outcome)`), then lavaan will treat it as an ordinal outcome.

Comment: @Joseph Clark McIntyre Thank you for your comment. I heard that generalized SEM can be built based on the binary outcome. Is it a correct statement?

Comment: You can fit a SEM with a binary outcome, yes.